# A new row in pdfptable

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am using iText library to print certain data in table format in a pdf file. I have 11 columns and can have multiple rows. After creating header for titles of each column, how do I create a new row in pdfptable so that I can print the real data on a separate row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the constructor of PdfPTable you specify the number of columns in a row.

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4) // 4 Columns
PdfPCell cell;
cell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase("Cell with colspan of 4") ) ;
cell. setColspan(4) ; // an entire row

anotherCell = new PdfPCell( new Phrase("Cell with colspan of 4") );
anotherCell.setColspan(4); // a second row
```

As you can see, a new row is created when you reach the colspan in the current row.

Comment: I guess I got it working by using table.completeRow(); so it finishes the row and starts a new row.

Comment: tks very much, In fact, a new row only is created when you reach the colspan. This is very important!