# need to create multiple rows in a table and place it in a middle of the page in PDF using itext

Tags: java, itext

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));
PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 4"));
PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 5"));
PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 6"));
PdfPCell cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 7"));
PdfPCell cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 8"));
document.add(table);
```

This code adds a table with 8 cells. what i need is, another row in the same table. what should i do..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A new row in pdfptable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891578/a-new-row-in-pdfptable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8); <-- This is a constructor. Above 8 cells, would automatically move to a new row.
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
PdfPCell cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));
PdfPCell cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 4"));
PdfPCell cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 5"));
PdfPCell cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 6"));
PdfPCell cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 7"));
PdfPCell cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 8"));

cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 1"));
cell2 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 2"));
cell3 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 3"));
cell4 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 4"));
cell5 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 5"));
cell6 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 6"));
cell7 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 7"));
cell8 = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("Cell 8"));
document.add(table);
```

// Samples / Examples:

```
    // a table with three columns
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    // the cell object
    PdfPCell cell;
    // we add a cell with colspan 3
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with colspan 3"));
    cell.setColspan(3);
    table.addCell(cell);
    // now we add a cell with rowspan 2
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with rowspan 2"));
    cell.setRowspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    // we add the four remaining cells with addCell()
    table.addCell("row 1; cell 1");
    table.addCell("row 1; cell 2");
    table.addCell("row 2; cell 1");
    table.addCell("row 2; cell 2");
```

Comment: i need a simple table with 2 rows and 8 columns. what u showed was a bit complicated..

Comment: @Srinivasan: The first part is very simple. Cannot be simpler!!! The second set of code is for your understanding of PDF Features.

Comment: the 1st set of code adds 2 Rows to a table..?? can u explain it how..?? bcoz it didn't work..!!

Comment: You will have to add  table.addCell(cell); after each row... That is why, i gave you the second set of codes. Hope it helps and works now!

Comment: okay... thanks 4 ur explanation..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359321/adding-row-to-a-table-in-pdf-using-itext check this question..!!