# Adding a row to a table in PDF using iText

Tags: java, itext

What I'm getting in this code is a table with 8 columns and 3 rows.

What should I do to get just 2 rows? And the 1st column in the 3 rows are empty, but the remaining cells are filled with "hi".

### Code:

---

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);

PdfPCell cell;

cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);

for(int aw=0;aw<8;aw++){
    table.addCell("hi");
}
```

Comment: visit these sites and play around with the examples asking for code will not help you in future. [refer1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html)[refer2](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-itext/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);

    PdfPCell cell;
    for(int aw=0;aw<8;aw++)
    {
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("hi"));
        table.addCell(cell );
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
    // Step 1
    Document document = new Document();
    // step 2
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(filename));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
   for(int aw=0;aw<16 ; aw++){
        table.addCell("hi");
    }



    // Step 5
    document.add(table);
    // step 6
    document.close();
```

See [SimpleTable](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleTable) for the full sample code and the [resulting PDF](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/simple_table.pdf):

[image]

As you can see in the screen shot, the table has 8 columns and 2 rows (as expected).

Reading the original question, I see that the first column has a cell with colspan 2. It's only a small change to take this into account:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("hi"));
cell.setRowspan(2);
table.addCell(cell);
for(int aw = 0; aw < 14; aw++){
    table.addCell("hi");
}
```

Now the result looks like this:

[image]

Again 8 columns and two rows, but now the cell in the first column spans two rows.

Comment: Nope. it didn't work..! i want to fill values too all the cells. and i need only 2 Rows. but i am getting 3..!

Comment: Is it still giving you 3 rows?? If so, how many colums are you getting?

Comment: i don't understand ur code.. y creating a cell b4 opening a document and creating a table after opening d document and adding cell, gives me 6 Rows with 8 columns..

Comment: Oops!! Forgot to mention the word "EDIT". Refer the edit version of the code.

Comment: Try only with the code mentioned below the "EDIT". Are you still getting 6 rows with 8 columns?

Comment: if i am using ur code i get 6 Rows & 8 Columns. if i use this in for loop `for(int aw=0;aw<8;aw++)` i am getting 3 Rows & 8 Columns.

Comment: Dear Srinivasan, maybe you're using an unofficial version of iText. I'll write you a POC using the official iText and I'll publish the result on the official iText web site. If, after seeing that proof, you still claim that you get another result, I'll down-vote your question and I'll vote to close it.

Comment: I published the sample code kindly provided by Nishanthi Grashia on the official iText site, I also published the resulting PDF, updated the answer by adding a screen shot that proves that Nishanthi Grashia's answer is correct, I up-voted Nishanthi Grashia's answer and down-voted Srinivasan's question because his behavior leads to believe that he's a troll rather than somebody with a genuine question.

Answer (score 0):

Your creating a table with 8 columns and adding 17 cells in total. This obviously results in three rows being created. Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);

for(int aw=0;aw<16;aw++){
    table.addCell("hi");
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same..! what i need is a simple table with 2 rows and 8 columns with all the cells filled with " hi "..

Comment: In that case, don't add the cell with the rowspan setting and just loop with `int aw=0;aw<16;aw++`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: this is my code now   `PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8); PdfPCell cell;

                       cell = new PdfPCell();
                       cell.setRowspan(2);
                       table.addCell(cell);

                       for (int aw = 1; aw < 8; aw++) {
                       table.addCell("hi");
                       } ` what your asking me to do now..?? should i remove `cell.setRowspan(2);`

Comment: So you have completely removed your code, and used mine instead?

Answer (score 0):

dear srinivasan the code you added will print only one row with 7 columns and first column will have rowspan2.
To print 8 rows ,you took table of 8 columns and in for loop for every increment of variable 'aw' one cell will be added to the table and for every multiple of 8 of 'aw' new row will be created.so to get 8 rows
try folowwing for loop in code:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(8);      
 for(int aw=0;aw<64;aw++)
 {
   table.addCell("hi");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

iText 7 in 2019.

When making a Table object, you specify the width as the number of columns you want to add.

```
int numberOfColumns = 10;
Table table = new Table(numberOfColumns);
```

Then you can set how wide you want the whole table to be etc.

```
table.setWidth(new UnitValue(UnitValue.PERCENT, 50));
table.setMaxWidth(new UnitValue(UnitValue.PERCENT, 100));
table.setFontSize(6f);
```

After which you can add cells with content and manipulate their look:

```
Cell cell = new Cell();
cell.setBorder(Border.NO_BORDER);
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("hi");
paragraph.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
paragraph.setBold();
//Instead of text you can add images and such in the same way
cell.add(paragraph);
//Insert cell into table
table.addCell(cell);
```

iText will simply keep adding your cells until it runs out of slots for cells on that row and then creates a new row by itself and starts injecting cells there.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to use.
Example using tile headers (name and lastName), that makes 2 columns, therefore:

Name  | Last Name
Alfa  | Beta
Gamma | Epsilon

'values' are my cells. I will just use

```
var table = PdfPTable(2)
values = ["Alfa", "Beta", "Gamma", "Epsilon"] 
for value in values{ 
  var cell = PdfPCell()
  cell.setPhrase(Phrase(reveza.cpfMotorista))
  table.addCell(cell)
  table.add(value) 
}
```

and the *itextpdf* will fill each cell (horizontally) from the table until it achieves 2 columns and will go to the next line.

[used kotlin language]