# Introducing a cell that spans two rows in a PDF table

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText (Java version) to create a PDF document as shown in the figure below:

[image]

I want to create content as shown in the highlighted part. I finished development of all the other parts of the PDF except, except for the highlighted part.

See:

[image]

Comment: Include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Sharing code as an image? Oh boy... In any case: why do you set the colspan and rowspan of cell 6 to 2? Why do you set the colspan of cell 20 to 2? Where are you adding the empty cells? Your code doesn't correspond with the image, and you did a great effort ordering the different lines of your code in the most confusing way. Are you leaving your company and angry with your successor? Don't you know the first rule of programming? It sounds like this: *Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.*

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by properly using Colspan and rowspan in iText. 
An example can be found below:

https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables/colspan-and-rowspan

I have added a small code block for the part I assume you'd be having trouble with:

```
public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    document.open();
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{ 1, 1, 1});
    PdfPCell cell;
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("8"));
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("10"));
    cell.setColspan(1);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("15"));
    cell.setColspan(1);
    cell.setRowspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("16"));
    cell.setColspan(1);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("17"));
    cell.setColspan(1);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("24"));
    cell.setColspan(1);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("25"));
    cell.setColspan(1);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("mm"));
    cell.setColspan(2);
    table.addCell(cell);
    cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("mm"));
    cell.setColspan(1);
    table.addCell(cell);
    document.add(table);
    document.close();
}
```

The resulting pdf looks like following: 
   [image]

I have used iText version 5.0.6

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: It is unclear if the OP uses iText 5 or iText 7. The code for iText 7 is quite different from the code for iText 5.

Comment: @MukulMoudgil No problem, could you share your code snippet?

Comment: I am using IText5

Comment: Where is the code snippet? Also iText 5 isn't precise enough. There's a huge difference between iText 5.0.0 and iText 5.5.12.

Comment: @MukulMoudgil Do not try to post code in a comment field. Update your question instead. Don't say things such as "I have done but was unable to achieve this." Instead show what you've tried, and what went wrong.

Comment: @MukulMoudgil I have added code to my answer. Try this and let us know.

Comment: @Yash Thank you for improving your answer, although it would have been better to close the question as a duplicate of [adding row to a table in PDF using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359321) instead of creating a new entry in Stack Overflow (too much redundant info).

Comment: Mmm. Yes sir, I didn't notice the answer was descriptive enough. I leave it up to your wisdom to call it a duplicate. :)